# Email followup on sharepoint stack exchange

Tags: feature-request

Is it possible to receive emails everytime somebody answer my questions or comments? I cant find a way to do it and I have to refresh every 10 minutes my questions to check for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ask a question at the bottom there is a link that say something like "do you want to receive an email when the question is answered". Select that and follow the guidelines and you should receive a mail when it is answered. Also the StackExchange dropdown on the top left of every page shows posts where your name is mentioned or when your questions are answered or commented on etc

[image: Screen capture from New Question]
[image: New question when email dialog is open]

Comment: I dont see that link in sharepoint stackexchange. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: I have added a screen capture of the screen as I see it. I can see you *have* registered an email account on your profile, so you should see it too...